# How to capture event of multiple Dynamic control in VB6.0

Tags: vb6, event-handling

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRX65.png)

In the above form, I have an SSTab. The Add Characteristics button is an added control to create rows of characteristics. On click of this button, I can keep adding Dynamic controls (Checkbox, Label, Text, Combobox and other controls.) Now I want to capture the Action. for Example, change of Text in Combobox or Change in CheckBox Status. I am not able to trap the Event to identify which control and what code will help me capture the action of a Dynamic Control (on the first Tab)

Can some one help me with a good solution? I have been desperately searching for over a month and have not got a solution so far.

Let me know how I can send the VB code as a ZIP file for reference over email.

Expectation:
1. I should be able to capture delete Row change in the check box
2. I should be able to capture changes in Combo box

Static Controls:
1. Form:        frmcharacteristics
2. Button: cmdAddCharacteristics
3. SSTab:   tabDisplay

Code in Module1:

```
Public SR_NO As Long
Public Top_Position As Long
```

code in frmCharacterisitcs:

```
Option Explicit
Dim WithEvents Ch_Delete_Row As CheckBox
Dim WithEvents Ch_SR_NO As Label
Dim WithEvents Ch_Name As TextBox
Dim WithEvents Ch_Type As ComboBox

Dim WithEvents Extended_Control As VBControlExtender


Private Sub cmdAddCharacteristics_Click()

    Module1.SR_NO = Module1.SR_NO + 1
    Set Ch_Delete_Row = frmCharacteristics.Controls.Add("VB.CheckBox", "Ch_Delete_Row" & (Module1.SR_NO), tabDisplay)
    Ch_Delete_Row.Visible = True
    Ch_Delete_Row.Top = Module1.Top_Position + 100
    Ch_Delete_Row.Width = 1000
    Ch_Delete_Row.Left = 500
    Ch_Delete_Row.Caption = ""
    Ch_Delete_Row.Height = 315
    'MsgBox Ch_Delete_Row.Name

    Set Ch_SR_NO = frmCharacteristics.Controls.Add("VB.Label", "Ch_SR_NO" & (Module1.SR_NO), tabDisplay)
    Ch_SR_NO.Visible = True
    Ch_SR_NO.Top = Module1.Top_Position + 200
    Ch_SR_NO.Width = 750
    Ch_SR_NO.Left = Ch_Delete_Row.Left + Ch_Delete_Row.Width + 400
    Ch_SR_NO.Caption = Module1.SR_NO
    Ch_SR_NO.Height = 315

    Set Ch_Name = frmCharacteristics.Controls.Add("VB.TextBox", "Ch_Name" & (Module1.SR_NO), tabDisplay)
    Ch_Name.Visible = True
    Ch_Name.Top = Module1.Top_Position + 100
    Ch_Name.Width = 2000
    Ch_Name.Left = Ch_SR_NO.Left + Ch_SR_NO.Width + 200
    Ch_Name.Text = ""
    Ch_Name.Height = 315

    Set Ch_Type = frmCharacteristics.Controls.Add("VB.ComboBox", "Ch_Type" & (Module1.SR_NO), tabDisplay)
    Ch_Type.Visible = True
    Ch_Type.Top = Module1.Top_Position + 100
    Ch_Type.Width = 1500
    Ch_Type.Left = Ch_Name.Left + Ch_Name.Width + 50
    Ch_Type.Text = ""
    'Ch_Type.Height = 315
    Ch_Type.AddItem "Service"
    Ch_Type.AddItem "Special"
    Ch_Type.AddItem "Option"

    Module1.Top_Position = Module1.Top_Position + 400
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Module1.SR_NO = 0
    Dim Test_Line As Control
    Set Test_Line = frmCharacteristics.Controls.Add("VB.Line", "LINE", frmCharacteristics)
    Test_Line.Visible = True
    Test_Line.X1 = 100
    Test_Line.Y1 = 600
    Test_Line.X2 = frmCharacteristics.Width
    Test_Line.Y2 = 600
    Top_Position = Test_Line.Y1
    frmCharacteristics.Show
    tabDisplay.Width = frmCharacteristics.Width - 1000
    tabDisplay.Height = frmCharacteristics.Height - 1500
    tabDisplay.Left = frmCharacteristics.Left + 200
    Call set_labels


End Sub


Sub set_labels()

    Dim Label_SR_NO As Control
    Dim Label_Name As Control
    Dim Label_Delete_Row As Control
    Dim Label_Type As Control

    Set Label_Delete_Row = frmCharacteristics.Controls.Add("VB.Label", "Label_Delete_Row" & (Module1.SR_NO), tabDisplay)
    Label_Delete_Row.Visible = True
    Label_Delete_Row.Top = Module1.Top_Position + 100
    Label_Delete_Row.Width = 1000
    Label_Delete_Row.Left = 300
    Label_Delete_Row.Caption = "Delete(Y/N)"
    Label_Delete_Row.Height = 315

    Set Label_SR_NO = frmCharacteristics.Controls.Add("VB.Label", "Label_SR_NO" & (Module1.SR_NO), tabDisplay)
    Label_SR_NO.Visible = True
    Label_SR_NO.Top = Module1.Top_Position + 100
    Label_SR_NO.Width = 750
    Label_SR_NO.Left = Label_Delete_Row.Left + Label_Delete_Row.Width + 400
    Label_SR_NO.Caption = "SR_NO"
    Label_SR_NO.Height = 315

    Set Label_Name = frmCharacteristics.Controls.Add("VB.Label", "Label_Name" & (Module1.SR_NO), tabDisplay)
    Label_Name.Visible = True
    Label_Name.Top = Module1.Top_Position + 100
    Label_Name.Width = 2000
    Label_Name.Left = Label_SR_NO.Left + Label_SR_NO.Width + 400
    Label_Name.Caption = "Characteristics Name"
    Label_Name.Height = 315

    Set Label_Type = frmCharacteristics.Controls.Add("VB.Label", "Label_Type" & (Module1.SR_NO), tabDisplay)
    Label_Type.Visible = True
    Label_Type.Top = Module1.Top_Position + 100
    Label_Type.Width = 1500
    Label_Type.Left = Label_Name.Left + Label_Name.Width + 50
    Label_Type.Caption = "Charac. Type"
    Label_Type.Height = 315

    Module1.Top_Position = Module1.Top_Position + 400
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code so we can see what is happening on the form?

Comment: Usually you start with a set of control with index 0 and then Load more instances and then the event handler for the original control gets events for all instances of the control with the Index passed a a parameter

Comment: Hi Guys, i have copied the code

Comment: from the combo, i need to capture change in values and display a message box which will show the Text displayed. For Checkbox, the message box can indicate the Status of Check box.... I am not able to capture the events for these actions.

Comment: Read @OldBoyCoder's comment.  It's a lot simpler than you're making it, unless I don't understand your requirement.  Use the `Load` statement to load more instances of the control.  You only need one event handler for each type of control, and which control has fired the event is captured by the `Index` property of the handler.

Comment: I tried that, with no luck. The control WithEvents is picking only the last control event